# angular2 Pipe expression on [ngClass] not working

Tags: angular, angular2-pipe

I have a Pipe to capitalize first letter in dynamic input string

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'capitalize'
})
export class CapitalizePipe implements PipeTransform {

transform(value: string, args: any[]): string {
if (value === null) return 'Not assigned';
return value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.slice(1);
 }
}
```

**Pipe is not accepting inside [ngClass] like**

> [ngClass]="data.color | capitalize">   // data.color is json input --> not capitalizing input string

```
<md-input-container>
    <input mdInput placeholder="Severity" value="{{ data.color }}" readonly>
    <md-icon [ngClass]="data.color+''|capitalize"></md-icon>
  </md-input-container>
```

When i print as {{data.color | capitalize}} it is working fine input = "name" 
prints as "Name". Any help would be great.

Comment: no error message?

Comment: no error messages found

Comment: even in the console? and is there a purpose of the args parameter in the transform function?

Comment: Try to delete the `args` in your transform function. You don't need it, and it appears as a required filed. Deleting it might solve your issue.

Comment: Its just array of second or third args right. Anyway removed and checked its not working

Comment: just for more information, if you do only data.color without a pipe in the ngClass is it working? because i tried uppercase pipe in plunker and it works perfectly

Comment: class="{{data.color | capitalize}}">

Comment: [ngClass]="{'className':true}">  is the correct syntax which you can't use it the way you want

Comment: or you can go with array [ngClass]="[data.color | capitalize]

Comment: [ngClass]="[data.color | capitalize] is not working. May be syntax is the prob ??

Comment: @marouanekadiri tried data.color  alone without pipe it is working fine

Comment: @Karthigeyan try the suggestion i posted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

```
[ngClass]="data.color+'' | capitalize"
```

Instead of:

```
[ngClass]="data.color | capitalize"
```

And check if you pipe is declared in the declarations of your module.
[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/d1ktGkBSpQZ66guIp3gc?p=preview) shows exact implementation.

Comment: Look at my [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/TTVTl1EHea2qJZedH2KN?p=preview) where i was testing

Comment: @Karthigeyan did you add your pipe in the declarations of your module?

Comment: @Karthigeyan [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/d1ktGkBSpQZ66guIp3gc?p=preview) show you the exact implementation of your problem.

Comment: plunker looks same as mine pipe is declared in module. I am checking is there any other prob.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153767/discussion-between-marouane-kadiri-and-karthigeyan).